# python - handle strings in a file with some Japanese in it

Tags: python-3.x, string, file

I have a .c file that I want to open with python 3 to update a specific number on a specific line.

It seems like the most common way to do this would be to read the file in, write each line to a temporary file, when I get to the line I want, modify it, then write it to the temp file and keep going. Once I'm done, write the contents of the temp file back to the original file.

The problem that I have, is that in the comments of the file there are Japanese characters. I know I can still read it in by adding the error equal ignore argument, that allows me to still read the lines in but it gets rid of the Japanese characters completely and I need to preserve those.

I haven't been able to find a way how to do this. Is there any way to read in a file that's part in Japanese and part in English?

Comment: could you provide some code to show how you're reading it?

Comment: You need to know the encoding of the file. Open it in Notepad++ for a good guess. Use `with open(file, encoding='utf8') as infile:` (or whatever the encoding actually is).

Comment: Sorry, don't have it in front of me to post at the moment. But I've been playing with file.open and codec

Comment: I'll check out the encoding and give it a try. Thanks!